# Spark - How many Executors and Cores are allocated to my spark job

Tags: python, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, executors

Spark architecture is entirely revolves around the concept of executors and cores. I would like to see practically how many executors and cores running for my spark application running in a cluster.

I was trying to use below snippet in my application but no luck.

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ExecutorTestJob")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
conf.get("spark.executor.instances")
conf.get("spark.executor.cores")
```

Is there any way to get those values using `SparkContext` Object or `SparkConf` object etc..

Comment: You can look in the Spark UI. Go to http://<driver_ip>:4040 and press the "Executors" tab. This varies between cluster managers.

Comment: Krishna, were you able to get ? feel free to ask questions

Comment: Were you able to test?

Comment: Thanks alot @RamPrasad. It helps alot. Tried with different datasets with different sizes and was able to get the executor nodes.

Comment: @yuval-itzchakov : Thanks Yuval.  It is working but when the spark application gets finished, the webUI with driverIP is shutting down. So, i was able to track through driverIP while the application is running. So, alternative i tried through JobTracker and was able to track the executors history. Thanks again.

Comment: @KrishnaReddy You can use the [history server](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html) for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Scala (Programmatic way) :

`getExecutorStorageStatus` and `getExecutorMemoryStatus` both return the number of executors including driver.
like below example snippet.

```
/** Method that just returns the current active/registered executors
        * excluding the driver.
        * @param sc The spark context to retrieve registered executors.
        * @return a list of executors each in the form of host:port.
        */
       def currentActiveExecutors(sc: SparkContext): Seq[String] = {
         val allExecutors = sc.getExecutorMemoryStatus.map(_._1)
         val driverHost: String = sc.getConf.get("spark.driver.host")
         allExecutors.filter(! _.split(":")(0).equals(driverHost)).toList
       }

sc.getConf.getInt("spark.executor.instances", 1)
```

similarly get all properties and print like below you may get cores information as well..

```
sc.getConf.getAll.mkString("\n")
```

OR

```
sc.getConf.toDebugString
```

Mostly `spark.executor.cores` for executors `spark.driver.cores` driver should have this value.

## Python :

[Above methods getExecutorStorageStatus and getExecutorMemoryStatus, In python api were not implemented](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext)

EDIT
But can be accessed using Py4J bindings exposed from SparkSession.

`sc._jsc.sc().getExecutorMemoryStatus()`

Comment: This is an old answer at this point, but I'm wondering how to accomplish this in R using sparklyr.  Any advice?

Comment: Pls ask another question with respect to sparkyr

Comment: Regarding python - It doesn't seem to work for me. I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342460) and included a minimal example for that. I'd appreciate some help if you can.

Answer (score 8):

This is an old question, but this is my code for figuring this out on Spark 2.3.0:

```
+ 414     executor_count = len(spark.sparkContext._jsc.sc().statusTracker().getExecutorInfos()) - 1
+ 415     cores_per_executor = int(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get('spark.executor.cores','1'))
```

Comment: Thanks, confirmed this today on pyspark 2.4 and it works.

Comment: Cannot confirm that the second one works: This will simply always output the number in the `get()` function! Example: `sc.getConf().get('anytexthere', "152")` will output **152**...

Answer (score -3):

This is python Example to get number of cores (including master's)
    `def workername():
    import socket
    return str(socket.gethostname())
anrdd=sc.parallelize(['',''])
namesRDD = anrdd.flatMap(lambda e: (1,workername()))
namesRDD.count()`

Comment: This snippet is only expected to return the number of executors that were used to calculate the lambda in `flatmap` (and that, given some corrections as well: using `countByKey` and swapping the constant 1 and the call for the method) which would in general be very different than the number of executors assigned to the application.