# Get number of active spark executors with sparklyr and R

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

When launching a spark cluster via sparklyr, I notice that it can take between 10-60 seconds for all the executors to come online.

Right now I'm using `Sys.sleep(60)` to allow time for them to come online, but sometimes it takes longer than that, and sometimes it is shorter than that.  I want a programmatic way to adjust for this time variance, similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163142/3790973) regarding Python.  So I think I want to pass `getExecutorMemoryStatus` via `sparklyr`, but I'm not sure how to do this.

To see what I'm seeing, run the following code to launch a yarn-client spark connection, and check the Yarn UI. In the *Event Timeline* we can see at which time each executor comes online.

```
spark_config <- spark_config()
spark_config$spark.executor.memory <- "11G"
spark_config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "11G"
spark_config$spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled <- FALSE
spark_config$`spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` <- "1G"
spark_config$spark.executor.instances <- 32

sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", config = spark_config)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So I think I want to pass getExecutorMemoryStatus via sparklyr, but I'm not sure how to do this.

You have to retrieve `SparkContext` object:

```
sc <- spark_connect(...)

spark_context(sc) %>%
  ...
```

and then `invoke` the method:

```
 ... %>% invoke("getExecutorMemoryStatus")
```

Together:

```
spark_context(sc) %>% 
  invoke("getExecutorMemoryStatus") %>% 
  names()
```

should give you a list of active executors.